# Would the following not be a correct proof of Cauchy's Integral Theorem?

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, contour-integration, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

I'm somewhat confused as to how the general version of Cauchy's Theorem does not follow (almost) immediately from its version in a disk. At least Ahlfors as well as Stewart & Tall prove the general theorem with arguments more complicated than the one I have in mind, which leads me to ponder: is the proof below wrong?

**Cauchy's Integral Theorem:** let $U\subseteq\mathbb{C}$ be an open set, with $\gamma$ be a piecewise smooth curve homologous to $0$ in $U$, and $f$ holomorphic in $U$. Then
$$\int_\gamma f = 0.$$

*Proof:* by the **[Paving Lemma](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Paving_Lemma)**, there is a finite collection of open balls $B_j$ centered at points $\gamma(t_j)$ of $\text{im}(\gamma)$ such that
$$\text{im}(\gamma)\subset\bigcup_j B_j.$$
WLOG we may assume $t_1<\cdots<t_m$. By **Cauchy's Theorem in a Disk** and the **Gradient Theorem** there are antiderivatives $F_j:B_j\to\mathbb{C}$ of $f$. As $[t_j,t_{j+1}]$ is connected, so is $B_j\cap B_{j+1}$, an open set where both $F_j$ and $F_{j+1}$ are defined and differ up to a constant. Adjusting $F_{j+1}$ by adding a constant, we find an antiderivative $F_{j,j+1}:B_j\cup B_{j+1}\to\mathbb{C}$ of $f$. Repeating this process as necessary we find an antiderivative $F:\bigcup_j B_j\to\mathbb{C}$ of $f$. The result now follows by the **Gradient Theorem.**

---

The following is **Theorem 6.44** in Stewart's & Tall's *Complex Analysis*. As it seems to me a form of the [Gradient Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_theorem) for $\mathbb{R}^2$, I call it by that name:

**Gradient Theorem:** Let $f$ be a continuous complex function defined on a domain $D$. Then the following conditions are equivalent:

1. $f$ has an antiderivative in $D$,
2. $\int_\gamma f = 0$ for every closed contour $\gamma$ in $D$,
3. $\int_\gamma f$ depends only on the end points of $γ$ for any contour $γ$ in $D$.

Comment: Hint: You never used the null-homologous assumption. The mistake is in the penultimate sentence of the proof.

Comment: @MoisheKohan you're right, I'm not using the null-homology and something is amiss. Why can't we construct the antiderivative $F$?

Comment: Oh! Is it because the last ball $B$ may intersect our previously constructed chain of balls in two different open sets, and the antiderivative in $B$ may differ by a different constant in each of these open sets?

Comment: Of course......

Comment: As an example, consider the unit circle traversed counterclockwise from $0$. This is not nullhomologous in $\mathbb{C}\setminus 0$, and indeed if you try to stitch together local antiderivatives of $1/z$ on elements of a finite open cover of the circle, you will end up with the first and last local antiderivatives differing by $2\pi i$.